# How to install surfnet/stepup-saml-bundle in symfony 2.3

Tags: php, symfony, saml-2.0

I'm trying to install **surfnet/stepup-saml-bundle** in symfony 2.3 but when I do a **composer require surfnet/stepup-saml-bundle** I'm getting this error:

> Problem 1
>       - Installation request for surfnet/stepup-saml-bundle ~1.7.0 -> satisfiable by surfnet/stepup-saml-bundle[1.7.0].
>       - Conclusion: remove symfony/symfony v2.3.11
>       - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.3.11
>       - surfnet/stepup-saml-bundle 1.7.0 requires symfony/dependency-injection ^2.7 -> satisfiable by
>   symfony/symfony[2.7.x-dev, 2.8.x-dev],
>   symfony/dependency-injection[2.7.x-dev, 2.8.x-dev, v2.7.0,
>   v2.7.0-BETA1, v2.7.0-BETA2, v2.7.1, v2.7.2, v2.7.3, v2.7.4, v2.7.5,
>   v2.7.6, v2.7.7, v2.7.8, v2.7.9, v2.8.0, v2.8.0-BETA1, v2.8.1, v2.8.2].
>       - Can only install one of: symfony/symfony[2.7.x-dev, v2.3.11].
>       - Can only install one of: symfony/symfony[2.8.x-dev, v2.3.11].
>       - don't install symfony/dependency-injection 2.7.x-dev|don't install symfony/symfony v2.3.11
>       - don't install symfony/dependency-injection 2.8.x-dev|don't install symfony/symfony v2.3.11
>       - don't install symfony/dependency-injection v2.7.0|don't install symfony/symfony v2.3.11
>       - don't install symfony/dependency-injection v2.7.0-BETA1|don't install symfony/symfony v2.3.11
>       - don't install symfony/dependency-injection v2.7.0-BETA2|don't install symfony/symfony v2.3.11
>       - don't install symfony/dependency-injection v2.7.1|don't install symfony/symfony v2.3.11
>       - don't install symfony/dependency-injection v2.7.2|don't install symfony/symfony v2.3.11
>       - don't install symfony/dependency-injection v2.7.3|don't install symfony/symfony v2.3.11
>       - don't install symfony/dependency-injection v2.7.4|don't install symfony/symfony v2.3.11
>       - don't install symfony/dependency-injection v2.7.5|don't install symfony/symfony v2.3.11
>       - don't install symfony/dependency-injection v2.7.6|don't install symfony/symfony v2.3.11
>       - don't install symfony/dependency-injection v2.7.7|don't install symfony/symfony v2.3.11
>       - don't install symfony/dependency-injection v2.7.8|don't install symfony/symfony v2.3.11
>       - don't install symfony/dependency-injection v2.7.9|don't install symfony/symfony v2.3.11
>       - don't install symfony/dependency-injection v2.8.0|don't install symfony/symfony v2.3.11
>       - don't install symfony/dependency-injection v2.8.0-BETA1|don't install symfony/symfony v2.3.11
>       - don't install symfony/dependency-injection v2.8.1|don't install symfony/symfony v2.3.11
>       - don't install symfony/dependency-injection v2.8.2|don't install symfony/symfony v2.3.11
>       - Installation request for symfony/symfony == 2.3.11.0 -> satisfiable by symfony/symfony[v2.3.11].
>
> Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original
>   content.

I tried `composer require surfnet/stepup-saml-bundle ~1.3.0` and change the version but keep getting the same.

Does someone know how to make this bundle work on a symfony 2.3 installation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I was able to do it was creating a fork of the bundle, then created a branch called sf23, modified the composer.json to change the dependence to symfony2.3, and add this to the symfony composer.json file in the repositories:

```
 { 
   "type" : "vcs",
   "url" : "for_url" 
}
and then did a:
    php composer.phar require "fork_bundle_name:dev-sf23"
sf23 is the name of the branch created with all the modifications
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the composer.json related to v1.3[image]

---

### Update

you can download the [zip file](https://github.com/Mehdi-CodeIsLife/Stepup-saml-bundle/archive/develop.zip) and extract it in vendor folder 
change the composer.json file as following:

```
"require": {
        "php": ">=5.4,<8.0-dev",
        "ext-openssl": "*",
        "simplesamlphp/saml2": "^1.8",
        "symfony/dependency-injection": "^2.3", // dep inject 2.3 !
        "symfony/framework-bundle": "^2.3",**   // sf 2.3 !
        "robrichards/xmlseclibs": "^1.4.0"
    },
```

Below the composer.json post-install-cmd :

```
"post-install-cmd": [
            "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::prepareDeploymentTarget"
        ],
```

you can proceed as said before, and run this command in order to run post install scripts

```
composer run-script [--dev] [--no-dev] script
```

Comment: I want to install it using composer because is part of an installation script, Is there a way to configure the composer.json script in symfony (not in the bundle) so it can download the bundle by just doing a composer install?.

Comment: i've update the answer, you can deploy the zipfile in vendor folder and run composer run-script [--dev] [--no-dev] script

Comment: I'm getting this: Script "script" is not defined in this package

Comment: What I'm trying to do is configure the symfony project composer.json so that when I do a composer install it download and install that Bundle. Right now I can't because it says that it can't satisfy the symfony 2.7 dependency

Comment: here is the exacte command =>  composer run-script post-install-cmd

Comment: for  can't satisfy the symfony 2.7 version you should change the version in your composer.json, pls post your composer.json

Comment: When running composer run-script post-install-cmd: Class Incenteev\ParameterHandler\ScriptHandler is not autoloadable, can not call post-install-cmd script and Method Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::prepareDeploymentTarget is not callable, can not call post-install-cmd script

Comment: pls post your composer.json file